# Textfield height is not decreasing in flutter | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

```
                 Container(
                    height: 30,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                          ),
                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          hintText: "Search Here",
                          fillColor: Colors.white70,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I want to reduce the textfield size, wrapping it with container and giving height is not working. is there any way to reduce the textfield size

Comment: It looks your code is right to mi

Comment: Set `isDense` to true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446697/changing-flutter-textfield-proportions

Answer (score 0):

Container(
width: 100.0,
child: TextField(
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 30.0,
height: 2.0,
)
)
)